# Data member property of datasource cannot be found

Tags: vb.net

I have a Winform to display the contents of two related data tables, `EquipReq` (the parent) and `EqReqItems` (the child).

After filling a new data set (`DS`) with both tables, I add a relation to the data set as follows:

```
DS.Relations.Add("RItems", DS.Tables("EquipReq").Columns("RecID"), DS.Tables("EqReqItems").Columns("ReqNo"), False)
```

I bind a new binding source `BS` as follows:

```
Dim BS As New BindingSource
BS.DataSource = DS
BS.DataMember = "EquipReq"
```

I (try) to bind another new binding source `BSI` as to the added relation `RItems` as follows:

```
Dim BSI As New BindingSource
BSI.DataSource = DS
BSI.DataMember = "RItems"
```

At this last line, I get the error "Data member 'RItems' cannot be found in the data source".

I have iterated through the relations of the data set `DS` and only one is shown with the name of `RItems`. I have also double-checked each data table to ensure the named columns in the relation exist in those tables.

Am I overlooking something obvious? What can I do to resolve this issue?

TIA,

Larry

Comment: Your first binding, `BS` sets `DataMember` to "EquipReq", which is the name of a table. But your second binding, `BSI` sets `DataMember` to the name of the relationship ("RItems") when it should likely be the name of the other table ("EqReqItems").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to set up parent/child data-binding then the child binding needs to be to the parent `BindingSource`, not the `DataSet`. You should add the `BindingSources` to the form in the designer, so they are accessible throughout the form code. Also, always set the `DataSource` last.

```vb
With parentBindingSource
    .DataMember = "ParentTable"
    .DataSource = myDataSet
End With

With childBindingSource
    .DataMember = "ParentChildRelation"
    .DataSource = parentBindingSource
End With
```

The reason you should set `DataSource` last, after `DataMember`, `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`, is that all the binding is set up when you set the `DataSource`. If you set it first then all the binding has to be changed when you then set the other property. If you set `DataSource` last then all the work of setting up the binding is done only once.

Comment: A thousand thanks, John! I was beating my head against the wall. Setting the child bindingsource's datasource to the parent bindingsource and setting the datasource of both bindingsources last did the trick. I guess this particular form was contankerous because I've used the same logic that I posted originally on previous forms in this app and they worked perfectly. Note that in your code above, the datamember of the parent bindingsource should read "ParentTable", not "ChildTable".

Comment: @LarryStinson, *" the datamember of the parent bindingsource should read "ParentTable""*. Indeed it should. Fixed.